# didSelectRowAt not getting called but delegate and dataSource are set

Tags: ios, swift

Here's my class

I set both `delegate` and `dataSource` but `didSelectRowAt` doesn't work  anyway. Is there anything I'm missing? I'm doing everything in code and don't have a storyboard at all.

```
class AddSubscriptionController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let cellId = "cellId"
    var subscriptions = [DefaultSubscription]()

    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()

    let addCustomSubscriptionButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Create Custom Subscription", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.separatorInset = .zero
        tableView.layoutMargins = .zero
        tableView.allowsSelection = true

        fillTableViewWithDefaultSubscriptions()

        addCustomSubscriptionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAddCustomSubscription), for: .touchUpInside)

        tableView.register(AvailableSubscriptionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(addCustomSubscriptionButton)

        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addCustomSubscriptionButton.topAnchor).isActive = true

        addCustomSubscriptionButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        addCustomSubscriptionButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        addCustomSubscriptionButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
        addCustomSubscriptionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
        navigationItem.title = "Add subscription"
    }


    private func fillTableViewWithDefaultSubscriptions() {
        subscriptions = [
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Amazon", price: 3.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Netflix", price: 7.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "iTunes", price: 2.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Yandex", price: 4.50),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Spotify", price: 9.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Dollar Shave Club", price: 5.00),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "ExpressVPN", price: 12.95),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Kinopoisk", price: 8.00),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "VK Music", price: 2.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Dota Plus", price: 4.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Steam", price: 0.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "YouTube", price: 11.99),
            DefaultSubscription(name: "Google Play", price: 5.99)
        ]
    }

    @objc private func handleAddCustomSubscription() {
        let customSubscriptionController = CustomSubscriptionController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: customSubscriptionController)
        present(navController, animated: true)
    }


    @objc private func handleCancel() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return subscriptions.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let subscription = subscriptions[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! AvailableSubscriptionCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = subscription.name
        cell.priceLabel.text = String(format: "$%.2f", subscription.price)
        cell.imageViewSubscription.image = UIImage(named: subscription.name)
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("TEST")
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `tableView.allowsSelection = true` explicitly? Do you have any custom tap handling on your cells?

Comment: It actually hits the breakpoint but doesn't call print

Comment: And if you resume after the breakpoint, is the print executed? Is any other code you put there executed? Have you tried the usual „rain dance” - clean, rebuild, restart simulator, clean install on simulator, restart Xcode, clean derived data? ;)

Comment: @Losiowaty Just tried everything, didn't solve the issue

Comment: @Losiowaty can dequeueReusableCell be the case by any chance?

Comment: Shouldn’t be, as this is the usual and recommended way to get the cells.

Comment: It might actually help if you just post all of your code in this case.

Comment: @ZGski I edited the question, that's my full class

Comment: You code works. Check that your debug window is set to All Output or instead of print try a simple alert.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell in `UIStroyboard`, and in Attribute Inspector, check the **User Interaction Enabled** box:

[image]